# Styled Component Button Extension

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

So my aim is to have a base button component and then a variant button which has the same markup as the base button but obviously has different styling, animations.

My base file is button.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import styled,{ keyframes, ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../../theme/default';

// import {rotatecw, rotateccw} from '../../../theme/keyframes';


const ButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  position: relative;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
  width: 256px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.grey};
      border: 1px solid ${(props) => props.theme.colors.grey};
    }
  }

`;

const ButtonText = styled.span`
  // transition: all 0.1s;
  // tranform: scale(1, 1);
`;


function Button(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ButtonWrapper>
        <ButtonText>  
          {props.text}
        </ButtonText>
      </ButtonWrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

So far so good.
My AnimatedButton file is like that

```
    import React from 'react';
import Styled, { keyframes, ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../../theme/default';
import Button from '../../components/button/button'

// import {rotatecw, rotateccw} from '../../../theme/keyframes';

const rotatecw = keyframes`
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
`

const rotateccw = keyframes`
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
`



const AnimatedButtonWrapper = Styled(Button)` 
transition: all 0.3s;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
  }
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    &:after {
      animation-name: ${rotatecw};
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    &:before {
      animation-name: ${rotateccw}; 
      animation-duration: 3s;
    }
    &:before,
    &:after {
      left: 96px;
      width: 64px;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
`;

function AnimatedButton(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AnimatedButtonWrapper>



      </AnimatedButtonWrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default AnimatedButton;
```

What confused me is the bottom part.  seems like a repeat ... How do I ensure it generates the same markup as Button ? I want my animated button to extend the markup and the css.
Eventually, is there a way to call my button this way

```
<Button animatedButton text="test"></Button>
```

Comment: Why not simply use CSS clases or join two objects for inline `style={...baseButton, ...variantA}`

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a `Button` with `styled(Button)`, you are essentially creating a more specific version of it and is planning to use the new specific one instead.

But when you want to use the button as:

```
<Button animatedButton text="test"></Button>
```

which is a variant passing in `animatedButton` as a prop, you are looking to incorporate these changes in the `ButtonComponent` itself.

```
const ButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  All the normal button stuff

  ${props.animated && `
    All the animation stuff goes here
  `}
`
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ButtonWrapper animated={props.animatedButton}>
        <ButtonText>  
          {props.text}
        </ButtonText>
      </ButtonWrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

If you have lots of variants as such, creating styles for these like this can be excruciating. This is why `styled-components` has a helper library [`styled-theming`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-theming) that can help out. (It isn't going be much help for the `animated` part since that's pretty much adding code rather than changing.